# How to group objects based on their properties into a table in an asp.net mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to ASP.NET MVC, I have a list of objects being passed to a view that I need to group into a table based on two of their properties. For example, each object have the following properties:

```
public class Student
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public int gpa;
    public string school;
    ...
}
```

In my view, I want to have a table where the columns are different ranges of gpa, and each row is a school. Within each cell in the table, I want to display the names of all the students from a specific school that belongs to a specific gpa range. Example:

List of students in the model:

```
Student{id=1, name="Alice",   gpa=3.5, school="School A"};
Student{id=2, name="Bob",     gpa=2.5, school="School A"};
Student{id=3, name="Charlie", gpa=1.5, school="School A"};
Student{id=4, name="David",   gpa=2.5, school="School B"};
Student{id=5, name="Ellen",   gpa=1.0, school="School B"};
Student{id=6, name="Frank",   gpa=2.5, school="School C"};
Student{id=7, name="Garry",   gpa=3.5, school="School C"};
```

The resulting table should look something like this in the view:

```
                  [0.0, 2.0)          [2.0, 4.0]
----------------------------------------------------------
School A          Charlie             Alice
                                      Bob
----------------------------------------------------------
School B          Ellen               David
----------------------------------------------------------
School C                              Frank
                                      Garry
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this when passing a list of unsorted objects into the view? This seems like a problem that can come up a lot, but I couldn't find any existing solutions. Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you define your range ?

Comment: The row and column headers will be pre-defined lists of values. Now that I think about it the range here is not the best exmaple. I'm mostly looking for exact-match just like the school property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you wanted to perform `GROUP BY` and can do that using a LINQ query.

```
var result =
    from student in studentList
    group student by new {student.school, student.gpa} into newGroup
    select newGroup;
```

Edit per your comment:

> How do I get specific value for example {"School A", 2.0}?

You can change your query

```
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student{id=1, name="Alice",   gpa=3.5, school="School A"},
            new Student{id=2, name="Bob",     gpa=2.5, school="School A"},
            new Student{id=3, name="Charlie", gpa=1.5, school="School A"},
            new Student{id=4, name="David",   gpa=2.5, school="School B"},
            new Student{id=5, name="Ellen",   gpa=1.0, school="School B"},
            new Student{id=6, name="Frank",   gpa=2.5, school="School C"},
            new Student{id=7, name="Garry",   gpa=3.5, school="School C"},
        };


        var result = from student in students
                     group student by new { student.school, student.gpa } into newGroup
                     select new 
                      {   Gpa = newGroup.Key.gpa, 
                          School = newGroup.Key.school, 
                          StudentName = newGroup.Select(x => x.name) 
                      };
```

You can now use a `WHERE` condition like

```
result.Where(a => a.School == "School A" && a.Gpa == 2.5)
```

> how can I use the "results" here to populate the table in my view?

If you want to pass this as model to your view then better you create a viewmodel and pass that to view and create a strongly typed view of that type like

Your viewmodel

```
public class StudentView
{
    public IEnumerable<string> StudentName { get; set; }
    public double Gpa { get; set; }
    public string School { get; set; }
}
```

Change the query to be then

```
        IEnumerable<StudentView> result = from student in students
                     group student by new { student.school, student.gpa } into newGroup
                     select new StudentView 
                      {   Gpa = newGroup.Key.gpa, 
                          School = newGroup.Key.school, 
                          StudentName = newGroup.Select(x => x.name) 
                      };
```

Now pass it to your view saying

```
return View(result);
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what is the "result" in this case? Do I substitute the "student.school" and "student.gpa" here for a specific value that I need, for example {"School A", 2.0}?

Comment: And how can I use the "results" here to populate the table in my view? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!